# Step-pyramid in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

**How can I generate a step-pyramid in LaTeX?**

I'm guessing I would use a graph module to centre chart bars...

I want to be able to select the length of each "row" of the pyramid, and show that number next to it, like so:
[image: Mockup]

Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: Those bars don't look centred. Should we assume that they are?

Comment: Yes, rocked this up in paint. Also assume that it isn't to scale!

Comment: @AT Shouldn't the 20 be 21?

Comment: -_- < "Not to scale"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest you use TikZ and a `\foreach` loop

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{barcolor}{named}{gray}
\definecolor{barborder}{named}{red}

\newcommand{\barheight}{0.5cm}

\newcommand{\pyramid}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm]
        \foreach \b [count=\n] in {#1} {
            \draw [barborder,fill=barcolor]
                (-0.5*\b,{(\n-1)*\barheight}) rectangle (0.5*\b,\n*\barheight);
            \node at (-0.5*\b,\n*\barheight-0.5*\barheight) [left] {\b};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    \pyramid{28,26,17,7}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**Usage/Notes**

- Us it with `\pyramid{<values>}` separate the values with commas `,`
  and sort the descending.
- Set the colors `barcolor` and `barborder` with `xcolor`.
- Change `x=0.25cm` to scale the image vertically.
- Change `\newcommand{\barheight}{0.5cm}` to set the height of the bars.
- You may want to add a font setting in the node like this

  ```
  \node at (...) [left,font=\small] {\b};
  ```
- It is also possible to align the numbers above each other.

  ```
  \newcommand{\Pyramid}[1]{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm]
      \foreach \b [count=\n] in {#1} {
                  % Store the first value in the list
          \ifnum\n=1\relax\xdef\firstbarwidth{\b}\fi
          \draw [barborder,fill=barcolor]
              (-0.5*\b,{(\n-1)*\barheight}) rectangle (0.5*\b,\n*\barheight);
          \node at (-0.5*\firstbarwidth,\n*\barheight-0.5*\barheight) [left] {\b};
      }
     \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  ```

  [image: result 2]

  (I changed the macro name to `\Pyramid`, with an uppercase `P`, so
  you can compare them in one document.)

Answer (score 8):

Minimalistic non-TikZ solution, with a bit of color and shade. Adjust to suit taste.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{ctr}
\newcounter{ctra}
\setcounter{ctra}{7}
\newlength\rwidth
\setlength\rwidth{50pt}
\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\loop
\ifnum\thectr<4
\fbox{\thectra}\colorbox{gray}{\color{olive}\rule{\the\rwidth}{30pt} }\\[-1.0pt]
\stepcounter{ctr}
\addtocounter{ctra}{7}
  \setlength\rwidth{\dimexpr\the\rwidth+30pt\relax}
\repeat
\end{center}
\end{document}
```