# Correct Placing of a pyramid in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a hierarchy pyramid with an arrow besides it and place it in the bottom right corner so everything is aligned.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, intersections}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily\small}}}

\tikzstyle{textbox}     = [rectangle, minimum width = 3.5cm, minimum height = 1cm, rounded corners = 1pt, line width = 1pt, draw = black, align = center]
\tikzstyle{curlyBrace}  = [decorate, decoration = {brace, amplitude = 15pt, raise = 2pt}, line width = 1pt, line cap = round]
\tikzstyle{arrow}       = [solid, line width = 5pt, -{Triangle[width = 10pt, length = 10pt]}]
\tikzstyle{singleArrow} = [single arrow, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 4cm, draw = black, line width = 1pt]


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 1cm, outer sep = 0]
        
        \node [textbox]                          (hut)   {hut};
        \node [textbox, right = of hut]  (fuss)  {fuss};
        \node [textbox, right = of fuss] (maus)    {maus};
        \node [textbox, below = 2cm of hut.west, anchor = west, minimum width = 8cm] (tao) {tao};
        \node [textbox, below = 2cm of tao.west, anchor = west, minimum width = 12.5cm]    (toll)    {toll};
        \node [textbox, below = 2cm of toll.west, anchor = west]  (wer)     {wer)};
        \node [textbox, below = 2cm of wer.west, anchor = west]  (mode)     {mode};
        
        \draw [curlyBrace] (wer.north east) -- (mode.south east);

        \coordinate (A) at (6,0)  {};
        \coordinate (B) at (14,0) {};
        \coordinate (C) at (10,4) {};
        
        \draw[name path = AC, line width = 1pt] (A) -- (C);
        \draw[name path = BC, line width = 1pt] (B) -- (C);
        
        \foreach \y/\A in 
        {0/{Hardware/Software/Bauteil},
            1/{System/Fahrzeugbereich},
            2/Fahrzeugmodell} {
            \path[name path = horiz] (A|-0,\y) -- (B|-0,\y);
            \draw[line width = 1pt, name intersections = {of = AC and horiz, by = P},
            name intersections = {of = BC and horiz, by = Q}] (P) -- (Q)
            node[midway, above] {\A};
        }

\node [singleArrow, anchor = east, rotate = 270] at (15,0) {Detailgrad};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I place the pyramid and the arrow next to it right under the box "toll" in the bottom right corner so everything is in line?

EDIT: Added an example image of the desired result.

[image: desired result]

Comment: One (promising) way is to use relative coordinates. Define coordinate A of pyramid as `\coordinate[left above=0 mm and 4mm of fuss.south east] (A)`. On similar way define others pyramid's coordinates. Also consider my answer on your previous question.

Comment: That is the problem! I already tried relative coordinates but I just get the same error like on my previous question. I tried 
\coordinate [below left = 4.5cm and 8cm of toll.east, anchor = east] (A) {};
\coordinate [below left = 4.5cm and 0cm of toll.east, anchor = east] (B) {};
\coordinate [below left = 1.5cm and 4cm of toll.east, anchor = east] (C) {};

Comment: Then your selection of relative coordinates is wrong. BTW, coordinates haven't any content, so you should write them for example as `\coordinate [below left = 1.5cm and 4cm of toll.east,] (C);`. Since their size is equal to zero, anchors know from nodes, hasn't any sense.

Comment: ok thanks :) But what is wrong about this coordinates. You can try in the example. it doesn't work.   
\coordinate [below left = 4.5cm and 8cm of toll.east] (A);
  \coordinate [below left = 4.5cm and 0cm of toll.east] (B);
  \coordinate [below left = 1.5cm and 4cm of toll.east] (C);

Comment: So far I didn't test your MWE, so I can't say, if your selection of coordinates is correct. Also, I don't know, how the image should be. If you will add some sketch of desired result, it will beeasier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does desired image should be like this:

[image]

The MWE, which produce above image, is based partly on the code from your MWE and wee bit modified code from the my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604362/tikz-error-when-creating-hierarchy-pyramid/604369#604369)  on your previous question:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, 
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be loaded after decorations.pathreplacing
                intersections,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style = {font=\sffamily\small, outer sep=0pt, line width=1pt},
          arr/.style = {-{Triangle[width=10pt, length=10pt]}, line width=5pt},% it is not used
           BC/.style = {decorate,
                        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                        raise=2mm},
                        very thick,
                        pen colour=black
                        },
          box/.style = {draw, rounded corners = 1pt,
                        minimum width = 21mm, minimum height = 7mm, inner sep=2mm,
                        align = center},
           SA/.style = {single arrow, draw,
                        minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 4cm}
        }


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 6mm
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes=box]
\node                   (hut)   {hut};
\node [right = of hut]  (fuss)  {fuss};
\node [right = of fuss] (maus)  {maus};
%
\node [below right = 4mm  and 0mm of hut.south west, 
       minimum width = 50mm] (tao)  {tao};
\node [below right = 4mm and 0mm of tao.south west, 
       minimum width = 76mm] (toll) {toll};
%
\node [below = of hut |- toll.south]    (wer)   {wer};
\node [below = of wer]                  (mode)  {mode};
    \end{scope}
\draw [BC] (wer.north east) -- (mode.south east);
% pyramid, positioned relative to nodes "toll" 
\coordinate[right=of toll.south east]   (A);
\coordinate[right=6cm of A]             (B);
\coordinate[above=4cm of $(A)!0.5!(B)$] (C);
% copy of my answer on the your previous question
\draw[name path = AB] (A) -- (C) -- (B);
%%
\foreach \y/\T in { 0/{Hardware/Software/Bauteil},
                    1/{System/Fahrzeugbereich},
                    2/Fahrzeugmodell}
{
\path [name path = H] ([yshift=\y cm] A) -- node [above, ] {\T} ([yshift=\y cm] B); % modified
\draw[name intersections = {of = AB and H, by = {p1\y,p2\y}}]
        (p1\y) -- (p2\y);
}
%%% single arrow
 \node [SA, rotate=270, right=6mm, anchor=east] at (B) {Detailgrad};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, but your question is not very clear (to me), where the pyramid and single arrow should be placed. However, the code in above MWE allows easy position adjustment of it. For example, that you like to have their bottoms aligned with the bottom of the image, you only need to determine coordinate A as:

```
% pyramid, positioned relative to nodes "toll" and "mode"
\coordinate[right=of toll.east |- mode.south]   (A);
```

In this case the produced image is:

[image]

Note: I took a liberty and define nodes as well piramide a bit smaller that now can be fit on a page.

Comment: thank you very much! I added an example image. Do you know how to do that so the arrow is in one vertical line with the other boxes like in the example picture?

Comment: @Bolle, of course I know, however the answer is structured and kas comments such that this you can easy do this yourself. You only need to determine new position of coordinate A. Since pyramid is quite tall, you will probably need to increase  vertical `node distance` and `minimum height`.

Comment: I do understand what you mean but the specific problem here is that i want the right corner of the arrow tip vertically aligned with the other boxes. Is it possible only by changing coordinate A?

Comment: @Bole, please try first if result will not be as you like to have, ask new question. As I see, determined od coordinate A should be sufficient (for example as  `\coordinate[right=of mode.south east]   (A);` ). Sorry, that I force you to make same experiments yourself (for starting point for them use my MWE). On this way you will learn more about Ti*k*Z  and better understand my MWE code :-)

Comment: is there an easy way to change the fill color of the pyramid?

Comment: @Bolle, this site is not a forum, If you have new question, please ask it as such. On this way more people will see it and can help you. In new question please show, what you try so far and where you stuck. Also clearly say, how you like to have colored your pyramid. The whole pyramid in the same border is simple.